# Firebird 3 connection string not working in C#

Tags: c#, firebird, firebird-3.0

I have a problem after migrating a database from Firebird 2.5 to Firebird 3. The C# application stopped displaying data. I have a 'REPORTER' user assigned to ROLE_SELECT, but not authorized to all tables. I guess the problem is with Fb-Connection because everything works fine in ISQL.

In ISQL:

```sql
connect "C: /database/data.gdb" user 'REPORTER' password 'xxxxxx' role 'ROLA_SELECT';
```

In C#:

```cs
FbConnection ("User ID = REPORTER; Password = xxxxxx; Role = ROLA_SELECT; database = C:/database/data.gdb; DataSource = localhost; Port = 3050;");
```

Everything worked fine in Firebird 2.5. Anyone know where the problem is in FbConnection?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Do you get an error? Which version of `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient` are you using.

Comment: Version: 5.9.1.0,

Comment: but on this version user SYSDBA work corectly

Comment: **I have a 'REPORTER' user assigned to `ROLE_SELECT`**  yet then we see....  `Role = ROLA_SELECT;`  - typo?  what do you see in `select mon$ROLE from mon$ATTACHMENTS` as shown in https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref-appx05-monattach ?

Comment: @Arioch'The yes, is typo... In select i see: `MON$ROLE
===============================
NONE
<null>
<null>`

Comment: but... if i logon to database from IBExpert on REPORTER (in the right field I type ROLA_SELECT) in `MON$ROLE` i see `ROLA_SELECT`

Comment: everything works fine on sysdba. The C # windows Form application connects seamlessly. If I enter the data of another user in the application, it shows no access. Data of other users are logged correctly in IBExpert ...

Comment: `SYSDBA` has full access to database regardless the settings.  Either you connect to different databsaes in your C# app and in IBExpert, or with different users or with different roles (ROLE_xx not ROLA_xx).  Use system and monitor tables to check, that you make connections to the same databse. Also check if your roles - both of them - were granted to both of your users. Notice that since Firebird 3 there are TWO user lists, one list from SRP auth plugin, and another from legacy auth plugin. And users of different plugins can have the same name

Comment: I am not sure, how would role assignment work if you have two users with the same name, one from SRP plugin and another from legacy plugin.  It might happen that you granted the role to legacy user AAA but revoked that role from SRP user AAA or vice versa. See `E.4 MON$DATABASE` and `F.3 SEC$USERS` and `D.29 RDB$ROLES` and `D.35 RDB$USER_PRIVILEGES` with M-kind privileges: https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html

Comment: Also, do edit your question, fix the typos there, add new refined information, etc. Do not burry it in comments heap

Comment: @Arioch'The Role assignment happens by name. So the authentication plugin is not involved. The only exception I know would be role assignment through a mapping rule.